What is the reason that the 10y forward shifted inverted Shiller PE Index predicts the S&P 500 10 year return this well?
I was watching a video by game of trades.
In the video he argues that the using the inverted Shiller PE Index shiftet 10y in the future can be used to predict the movement of the S&P 500 10 year return.
He argues that the Shiller PE can be used in this manner to predict long term market movements of the S&P 500.
The chart show quite good correspondence if you want to invest long term. Is this strategy used and is it a valid strategy?


I'm very skeptical about seeing charts that are scaled (and inverted in this case) to "magically" line up, but I am curious  what each line is supposed to represent?  There may be fundamental reasons that explain the correlation (not causation)

For example, is the PE graph suggesting that the SP500 will just go down over the next 10 years (the line from "21" to "31")? Or does it indicate that it will go down A LOT as the black line trends more towards the orange line over the next 10 years?

@DStanley He basically takes the Shiller PE, shifts it forward 10y and inverts it and the outcome is the orange graph. Black is just the S&P 500 10 year return plotted on a monthly resolution
